# Bound of an infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to show that the following series is less then 1/2:

$$\sum_7^\infty 2^{n^2-2^{(n-1)}}\, < 1/2.$$

any help?
thanks!

Comment: Uh, did you mean to change that to a $7$?

Comment: yes. sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use that, for $n\ge7$,
$$
0\le 2^{\large n^2-2^{n-1}}\le2^{\large n^2-2n^2}\le 2^{\large -n^2}\le2^{-n}
$$ and that
$$
\sum_{n=7}^\infty 2^{-n}=\frac1{64}.
$$

Comment: You beat me on the timer. (+1)

Comment: @Neta_1990 You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$2^{n-1}$ grows faster than $n^2$ so that the general term decreases much faster than a geometric progression and the sum is certainly bounded.

The first exponents are

$$-15,-64,-175\cdots$$ and the sum must be below $2^{-14}=2^{-15}+2^{-16}+2^{-17}+\cdots$.